# How to get choices from lookup field using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, mvc

I have an MVC app and am trying to recreate a Lookup site column on a page with a drop down list (add all the choices to the list). The itemColl ends up being empty, is there something that I'm not loading correctly?

```
SharePointContext spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
ClientContext clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost();
Field field = clientContext.Web.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle('InternalName');

clientContext.Load(field);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

FieldLookup lkField = clientContext.CastTo<FieldLookup>(field);
clientContext.Load(lkField, f => f.LookupList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(lkField.LookupList));

var itemColl = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
clientContext.Load(itemColl, items => items.Include(listItem => listItem[lkField.LookupField]));
clientContext.Load(itemColl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hack into the schema of the field:

```
ctx.Load(field, (s) => s.SchemaXml);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var lookupListId = XElement.Parse(field.SchemaXml)
                              .Attributes()
                              .First(s => s.Name == "List")
                              .Value;
```

See:
[Convert Field To FieldLookup using ClientContext](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55328/convert-field-to-fieldlookup-using-clientcontext)

Comment: I was able to get around the issue by changing to CastTo instead of as (8th line). I am still not able to actually get any items though (itemColl is empty). Do you know if there's something else I'm not loading to the context correctly?

Comment: My only other thought was to target your SP List based field, versus your  Web fields collection, but that might be a red herring.

Comment: I just figured it out actually, I didn't have the right permissions in my app to access the list. Can't believe I missed that